# How would I go about listening to a route change in reach router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reach-router

I have a component I'm trying to build pagination functionality for

```
<PageNumber>
   <StyledLink to="/visited/page/1">1</StyledLink>
   <StyledLink to="/visited/page/2">2</StyledLink>
</PageNumber>
```

so when I click the link it should change the path (which it does)

the problem is my component does not re-render so I can't seem to then display page 2 (even though the route has changed)

how can I listen to the changes in my component? I'm using hooks

I've searched the docs and all the options seem to indicate you should only listen to route changes using `LocationProvider` and stuff for testing

```
        <Router>
            <Visited path="visited/page/:id" />
            <AllCountries path="all" />
            <Map path="map" />
            <Redirect from="visited" to="page/1" />
        </Router>
```

Comment: Could you provide a Demo link (codesandbox, ....)?

Comment: How are you changing the routes

Comment: please see updated code showing my router component. I display all the routes inside there and then I just import link in other components to link to them @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: ok I figured what I can do. I can have 2 useEffect functions and listen to props in one of them

Comment: @RedBaron can you elaborate? I'm trying to detect route changes before navigating away from a form but it's been rough